# Have segue push animations really changed in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have just changed my app to iOS 7 only, and noticed that the Push Segues have changed their animation.

Previously 2 viewControllers animated in/out **side-by-side**, at the same speed.
But **now**, the incoming viewController animates quicker, **over the top** of the slower, outgoing segue.

I cannot find this change reported anywhere. Is it really a change in the OS, or is my app being weird!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of the navigation view controller’s push animation has changed between iOS 6 and iOS 7: as you’ve noticed, there’s now a sort of depth/parallax effect to the animation. You can see it for yourself in any of the system apps that use a navigation controller, e.g. Settings.

Comment: Yes you're right. I've literally just installed iOS 7 and can see the same animations in settings. Well well, looks like I will have to do some custom segues, because I want the side-by-side animation. What fun. Thanks Noah.